# Product image upload issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image-upload

I have recently upgraded a client to Magento 1.9.3.3 using a fresh install but I am finding an issue when uploading product images.

In admin panel I receive a successful upload message but no image.... I can see the image in the media/tmp directory but it doesn't seem to be getting past this stage.

When I use console there are no errors. I can see a request is sent on clicking "Upload Files" to

> index.php/admin/catalog_product_gallery/upload/key/2d462e56a‌​b5f1b53daf320d83e473‌​14f/?SID=1b80b8af93e‌​6f4790e27bab5ab360ea‌​3

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: any error through.  check inspectelement and let me know

Comment: When I use console there are no errors... I can see a request is sent on clicking "Upload Files" to `index.php/admin/catalog_product_gallery/upload/key/2d462e56ab5f1b53daf320d83e47314f/?SID=1b80b8af93e6f4790e27bab5ab360ea3`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, this is still an issue